# Trimfill for rma.mv models in Metafor packlage

Tags: r

New to R and trying to run a metanalysis using Metafor package, but struggling with the publication bias analyses.

I'm trying to analyze publication bias in the Metafor package for an analysis (`rma.mv` model) that includes phylogenetic control (distance matrix from a phylogenetic tree). Nakagawa and Santos 2012 recommend using the residuals of the phylo model in either a trim and fill analysis or an Egger's regression. I understand the principle, but am having problems executing it. Here is what I have done:

```
ES_Calc <- rma.mv(yi=yi, V=vi, random= ~1|PhyloName, R=list(PhyloName=PhyCor),Rscale="cov0", data=ES)  #this model works well! ES is a dataframe with columns for the effect size yi, variance, vi, and species name PhyloName. PhyCor is a distance matrix between all species.

Resid <- rstandard(ES_Calc)  #I recover residuals, se, z, slab with 110 datapoints each
```

Here is where I run into problems with the approach. The Egger's regression (`regtest`) and trim and fill (`trimfill`) both require the input of a meta-analysis (rma.uni output), so there are two options I can think of and am not sure which is right:
1) Somehow convert the Residuals output to a format similar to rma.uni - but I have no idea how to do this. Anyone know?

2) Convert the Residuals output to a dataframe (it is a list, but I need a dataframe for running an rma analysis):

```
Resid_DF<-do.call("rbind", Resid)
Resid_DF22 <- t(Resid_DF)
```

Then run an rma.uni on the residuals data and run either trimfill or regtest:

```
resid.es <- rma(yi=resid, vi=se, data=Resid_DF2)
trimfill(resid.es, estimator="R0")
regtest(resid.es)
```

But in this second option, I am not at all confident that the approach is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simply run the Egger's regression using the residuals and the original effect size variances.

`eg.reg1 = lm(residuals.rma(ES_Calc)~data.frame$vi)`

where data.frame$vi are the original effect size variances from your dataset. By using the residuals from your rma.mv object you are accounting for the heterogeneity that is explained by the random effects terms in your model.